# Widget is appearing next to image?

Tags: python, image-processing, pyqt, pyqtgraph, roi

I am attempting to put pyqtgraph ROI widgets (information [here](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/roi.html)) on top of a .PNG image. When I import the image into the program, it comes out rotated and flipped the wrong way. I assume this is a bug. To attempt to fix it, I have rotated the image BUT when I do so, my ROI widget goes off of the image. How do I fix this?

**Without image rotation:**

```
i = Image.open("del.png")  
a = array(i) #converting to numpy array 
img1a = pg.ImageItem(a)
v1a.addItem(img1a)
```

Once I add `img1a.rotate(90)` to the code above, the ROI widget goes off the screen. *How do I position the image the correct way and have my ROI widget appear normally on top of the image?*

**The entire code is found below (edited from this example found [here.](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/downloads/0.10.0/pyqtgraph-0.10.0-deb/pyqtgraph-0.10.0/examples/ROIExamples.py))**

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from PIL import Image

## create GUI
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
w = pg.GraphicsWindow(size=(1000,800), border=True)
w.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: ROI Examples')

text = """text"""
w1 = w.addLayout(row=0, col=0)
label1 = w1.addLabel(text, row=0, col=0)
v1a = w1.addViewBox(row=1, col=0, lockAspect=True)
#img1a = pg.ImageItem(arr)

i = Image.open("del.png")
a = array(i)
img1a = pg.ImageItem(a)
v1a.addItem(img1a)
img1a.rotate(90)
v1a.disableAutoRange('xy')
v1a.autoRange()

rois = []
rois.append(pg.EllipseROI([150, 150], [1, 1], pen=(4,9)))
rois.append(pg.EllipseROI([0, 0], [300, 300], pen=(4,9)))

for roi in rois:
     v1a.addItem(roi)

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to rotate the item, but you must rotate the image for it you can use [numpy.rot90](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html):

```
i = Image.open("del.png")
a = array(i)
a = np.rot90(a, -1)
img1a = pg.ImageItem(a)
v1a.addItem(img1a)
v1a.disableAutoRange('xy')
v1a.autoRange()
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.